# How to make the CSS width property go from bottom to top

Tags: html, css, webkit, google-chrome-app

I'm making a web app for Google Chrome (so no need for cross browser support) and I'm making an animated tutorial that will run when it first boots. I'm drawing a box on the screen by having four different div elements with `-webkit-transistions` for width and height properties respectively.  Then I'm using javascript to add classes to these borders and make them draw on the screen. It was all working fine until I got to the border on the right-hand side. I want my borders to draw like this: left goes down, bottom goes right, right goes up and then top goes left. It all worked properly until I got to the right border. It draws from top to bottom instead of bottom to top. I tried rotating it with `-webkit-transform:rotate(180deg)` but that didn't really help. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
button {
    background-color:lime;
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, lime, green);
    border:solid 1px 000000;
    cursor:hand;
    border-radius:10;
    outline:none;
    width:50px;
}
.left {
    width:5px;
    height:0%;
    border-right:solid 1px 000000;
    background-color:ffffff;
    -webkit-transition:height 2s;
}
.bottom {
    width:0%;
    height:5px;
    border-top:solid 1px 000000;
    background-color:ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    left:13px;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s;
}
.right {
    width:5px;
    height:0%;
    border-right:solid 1px 000000;
    background-color:ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    right:11px; 
    top:10px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    -webkit-transition:height 2s;
}
.top {
    width:0%;
    height:5px;
    border-bottom:solid 1px 000000;
    background-color:ffffff;
    position:absolute;
    left:13px;
    top:7px;
    -webkit-transition:width 2s;
}
.leftdraw {
    height:99%;
}
.bottomdraw {
    width:98%;
}
.rightdraw {
    height:96.5%;
}
.topdraw {
    width:98%;
}
</style>
<script>
function begintut() {
    document.getElementById("left").classList.add("leftdraw")
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('bottom').classList.add('bottomdraw')",2000)
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('right').classList.add('rightdraw')",4000)
    setTimeout("document.getElementById('top').classList.add('topdraw')",6000)
}
</script>
<title>Tutorial - Inscribe</title>
</head>
<body onload="begintut()">
<div class="left" id="left"></div><div class="bottom" id="bottom"></div><div class="right" id="right"></div><div class="top" id="top"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue lies with your initial position of the top and right divs.  If you make the following changes to your right and top classes, I think you will achieve your desired effect.

.right
change top:10px; to bottom:10px;

.top
change left:13px; to right:13px;